# @font-face: font in FF is bolder than in Opera 17 or Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, icons, font-face

I used this code for font-based icons:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'LG simboliai';
src:url('../fonts/LG simboliai.eot?-8dz81a');
src:url('../fonts/LG simboliai.eot?#iefix-8dz81a') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('../fonts/LG simboliai.ttf?-8dz81a') format('truetype'),  url('../fonts/LG simboliai.woff?-8dz81a') format('woff'),  url('../fonts/LG simboliai.svg?-8dz81a#LG simboliai') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
.lg-icon {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'LG simboliai';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1";
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga";
-ms-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
-o-font-feature-settings: "liga";
font-feature-settings: "liga";
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

And icons in Firefox is too much bolder. How to solve this?

I have to use the fonts from local files. Problems is only on mac's firefox.

Example: http://igor.lt/upload/font/

Comment: If you don't mind firefox specific css, try to set font-weight:200; just for FF.

Comment: @vladsaling, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post a working example somewhere with that font?

Comment: Here you are http://igor.lt/upload/font/

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any differences between browsers.

Comment: @MrLister, try with Mac OS X Firefox

Comment: @Igor Sorry. Linux at home, Windows at work. That's it. Do the problems exist with other fonts too? Then you should check out the gfx.font_rendering... entries in about:config. Maybe something isn't right in there.

Comment: @Igor thnx, will try it as soon as possible